# Print all files on a filesystem using system call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am  working in the kernel and I am trying to make a system call that takes a partition as input (i.e. `/dev/sda1`) and then prints **every** file on the filesystem using `printk()`.
I enter a partition (i.e. `/dev/sda1`) and I put a `printk()` inside this system call to print.

First, I tried to do this with a process, because if I am right each process is represented by a `task_struct` and I tried to access the files with the `files_struct`. But the problem is that I only have the file descriptors of the opened files and not all the files.

So, what I want to do is that I pass the name of the partition and I `printk()` the names of all the files.

---

For example:

I enter the path `/dev/sda1` as an argument and let's suppose I have the file `a.txt` and `b.txt` inside this partition , so the system call should print `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

The signature will be like this:

```
asmlinkage long sys_acall(char *partition_name);
```

Comment: Do you mean all files recursively? Or just the files and folders in the root of that partition?

Comment: Partitions don't contain files, filesystems do. You're going to need to traverse the filesystem recursively, exactly like `find` and other commands. For that matter... why can't you just use `find`?

Comment: @Kevin Yes,I would like to this recursively.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you'll have to implement it yourself, especially working at the kernel level.

Comment: Is this for the development of your own filesystem … ? Perhaps rather than creating a new syscall, you might consider hooking into an ioctl, in that case?

Comment: @Chris Thank you ,I will change the title .

Comment: @all So,I think I will give up doing this ,probably I will spend a lot of days or months doing this.Thank you.

Comment: I think it might be a bad idea. Your syscall will take essentially an unbounded (i.e. very large) amount of time, to produce an unbounded amount of output. No syscalls do this.... (they all give a bounded reply).

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things that needs to be discussed.

- The partition_name parameter of your syscall should have the __user tag.
- If you want to, strictly speaking, read files from a partition you will have to implement filesystem recognition (is that partition ext3, reiserfs, ntfs, ...?) and then implement the driver for that kind of filesystem. As Christ pointed out, partitions doesn't contain files but filesystems does. Another option is use the drivers already implemented for the filesystem on that partition. This option is just horrible.
- If you want to read files from a filesystem your work gets easier, you can use the VFS interface to access it, but you will need that filesystem to be mounted (you can do it on-the-fly though).

My final opinion, I would change "implement a system call that prints every file in a partition" for "implement a system call that prints every file in a directory". The signature for that system call would be:

asmlinkage long sys_crazyness(__user const char *dir);

We don't care if the directory passed is the root of a filesystem or just a folder in any depth-level of a filesystem.

If you can change your problem to this one it would be much easier ;)